# Bursts of plot development versus slow rising action

Tags: technique, plot, suspense

From most of the stories I've read, the plot development tends to follow a smooth curve. This has obvious advantages given the reader can start to use his/her imagination more, anticipating/worrying about what could happen next. In many cases this is fun and a desirable outcome. However, in some applications might it not be better to throw the reader into the fray with a more jagged plot development curve. Take the "square" series below:

[image]

I would imagine this would accomplish my goal of making it harder to anticipate what happens next. Although, since the troughs would have substantial details -- many without substantial implications -- this would be transgressing against certain principles like [Chechov's Gun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chekhov%27s_gun). However, in my opinion at least, this would create a more effective environment to create anxiety. That is to say, the corollary of Chechov's Gun is you have to show more of your hand than you may want to if you want not just to surprise the reader but totally *blindside* them.

### Question

Is it still considered professional to use a "square/jigsaw" plot development cycle? What prominent pieces stand out among this category in the literature?

Comment: Your square wave could represent split perspective between 2 protagonists (especially where they are at opposite ends of the conflict), and sawtooth might be like Saturday matinee serials leading to cliffhangers that are easily resolved at the beginning of the next episode...  But this is a limited analogy because narratives do not oscillate between 2 states (not without criticism of predictability).

Comment: What is the Y axis supposed to represent here? And what's really the difference between a jagged curve and a smooth curve? Such graphs are a subjective interpretation of events. (It would be much clearer to me if you talked about the effect you want, without bringing graphs into it at all.)

Comment: If Y axis reflects tension/tempo, then the square chart approximately correspond to the Action genre. Slow development is followed by a fast pacing fight/chase scene, which then falls back to slow moving scene. Slow/fast pace keeps switching from the beginning to the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In many cases the "curve" towards the climax of the story is actually less smooth than appears.

What it actually looks like is something more like this:

[image: Plot Curve]

Yes the *general* trend is towards a greater intensity (i.e. the dotted line) but the actual path of the plot is closer to your saw tooth plot.

> I would imagine this would accomplish my goal of making it harder to anticipate what happens next. Although, since the troughs would have substantial details -- many without substantial implications -- this would be transgressing against certain principles like Chechov's Gun.

You've got to be careful in this. If your "troughs" are obviously not moving the main plot forward you risk boring or frustrating the reader, pacing *matters* and if you're going to slow the plot development down somewhere in the last act you're definitely going to need a damn good reason or it's going to fall flat on it's face.  Alternatively if the troughs *look* like they might be moving the plot forward or setting up subplots only to be abandoned later then it's just going to look sloppy.

Chekhov's Gun is a fine story-telling principle - although ultimately it's one that many people misunderstand slightly. Frequently people take it to mean that if something presents an obvious purpose that it must fulfill *that* purpose. A loaded rifle must be fired etc. But the key concept is that that every element in a story must contribute to the story, and irrelevant elements should be removed. An intentional misdirect, a red herring in a mystery or mundane details of a character's day-to-day life can all serve a purpose in the story, whether that's setting up a twist, adding complexity or helping the reader understand a character better and make the story better as a result.

If removing a story element makes either improves the story or makes no appreciable difference then, well, it probably shouldn't be there.

There's nothing wrong with playing with with the principle or out and out subverting it every now and again. Indeed, applying it *too* strictly can result in a boringly predictable narrative - although from a certain point of view if you're including a few inconsequential details to prevent the story being too predictable they *do* serve a purpose and therefore actually adhere to Chehkov.

But as regards direct subversions it's that "now and again" part that's the key - if you set up 10 Chekhov's Guns but only fire one of them you're going to end up with a bloated, wandering narrative where the actual plot gets lost in the mire if you're not careful. Many readers will also (at least subconsciously) pick up on the Guns and get a sense of the sort of story they're reading and too many mixed signals will just confuse the reader.

Some authors disdained Chehkov's stance entirely - Hemmingway for one, and I must stress that there's no hard and fast rules or laws, the Chekov police aren't going to come knocking down your door if you leave that loaded gun hanging on the wall the whole damn story. But most authors apply it in a general sense - even if in the most basic meta sense of asking yourself as the author what a particular scene or element adds to the story.

> However, in my opinion at least, this would create a more effective environment to create anxiety.

I'm not sure if English is your first language here but I'm not sure "anxiety" is quite what you want to be aiming for - anxiety is not generally a pleasant emotion, and outside of certain genres e.g. horror it isn't really why people read. Creating *uncertainty* is fine - it's okay if your reader doesn't know if everyone makes it out alive for example.

> That is to say, the corollary of Chechov's Gun is you have to show more of your hand than you may want to if you want not just to surprise the reader but totally blindside them.

Big twists that blindside the reader can be great tools - but you can't pull them off continually through the story, you can maybe do two or three max before they just lose any effect or impact. Quite quickly your reader will reach a point where they don't know what *is* going to happen but they know it's not what they would normally expect, and that becomes it's own kind of predictable.

The key to pulling off a *really* successful big twist well is to set them up but to do so subtly, even better if you can show them that Gun but convince them it's a spoon, in a way you're aiming for "obvious in hindsight".

If you look at stories like *The Sixth Sense* or *The Usual Suspects* both lay out a surprisingly large amount of ground work for their "blindsiding" twists, all the while doing their level best to persuade you that those guns are actually spoons and you should pay no mind to them.

You don't want the reader to see your twist coming but you do want it to make sense to the reader once it arrives and keeping twists grounded in the narrative this way helps keep them believable rather than absurd. No-one would have seen it coming if at the end of *Lord of the Rings* Frodo was revealed to be an alien from Omicron Persei 8 who did the whole thing just to study the primitive culture of Middle Earth But it wouldn't have been a good twist - just a nonsensical one.

Answer (score 2):

One cannot quite as easily categorize stories into these few different narrative structures. In fact, there are [more narrative  structures](https://blog.reedsy.com/guide/story-structure/) than just the few you have listed exist, and every structure is used for different purposes. "Everything I never told you" by Cleeste Ng, is listed as one of the examples for the jigsaw type of narrative.

I'ver never heard of the square type structure, although wetcircuit might have given the best example of this. To make something unpredictable, it requires not any one of these structures, but a mix of them. In the Song of Ice and Fire series, for example, the first book had rising action to the end of the book. The second book made use of an epic narrative structure, where there were several conflicts that occur throughout the book, while the third book used the Fichtean structure (like outlined in the article). I haven't read the rest.

At no point, could the reader anticipate what structure the author was using until it was too late.

Either way... making things unpredictable *and enjoyable* is difficult, because though narrative turns must be unpredictable, the reader needs to accept this unpredictability. Darth Vader's reveal that he was Luke's father, for example, was readied in advance, because we knew/thought that Luke was an orphan because of Vader, which was what made the conflict in Star Wars: Episode 7 meaningful.

At the same time, making too many unpredictable moves, or ones that are spaced out in predictable ways as your curves suggest, would destroy the unpredictability. In the second part of ASOIAF book 3, the twists arrived faster and faster, instead of at the same pace, while there was also rising action. A Square structure would make the turns boring. Unless of course, there was rising action, but then it wouldn't be a square curve.